# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') using pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas, xlsx

I keep having the following error. you should know that file name is correct and this pandas method works in other py files, please help !!!!

the tablecouleurs is an excel table with no specific characters

```
import pandas as pd

colors=pd.read_excel('C:\Users\paul\tablecouleurs.xlsx', index_col=0, has_index_names=True)
```

and error:

> runfile('C:/Users/paul/Documents/colors.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/pauldufosse/Documents') Traceback (most recent call
> last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> runfile('C:/Users/paul/Documents/colors.py', wdir='C:/Users/pauldufosse/Documents')
>
> File
> "C:\Users\paul\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
> line 685, in runfile
> execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\paul\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
> line 71, in execfile
> exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/paul/Documents/colors.py", line 12, in
>
> colors=pd.read_excel('C:\Users\pauldufosse\tablecouleurs.xlsx', index_col=0, has_index_names=True)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\paul\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
> line 151, in read_excel
> return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\paul\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py",
> line 188, in **init**
> self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\paul\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init*_.py",
> line 394, in open_workbook
> f = open(filename, "rb")
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
> 'C:\Users\paul\tablecouleurs.xlsx'

Comment: Have you tried with forward slashes? You have a \t (..sse\tabl..) in that filename (tab character) so maybe that's why it's failing?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. You can solve it by double escaping your path.

The error messages says:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\Users\pauldufosse\tablecouleurs.xlsx'
```

Just do:

```
foo = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\pauldufosse\\tablecouleurs.xlsx')
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
open_workbook f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

If you check Python library you will see you have to use single quote instead of double quote.